# Querying tables: complex join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have this query and it does a great job when there are matching rows on table `Tiempo`.

The problem is that what I really need to see are the no-matching rows in `Tiempo`, that exists also in `Usuario` too.

```
SELECT u.Id, t.empleado, CAST(MONTH(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS MonthNumber, CAST(YEAR(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS YearNumber, SUM(t.horas) AS Horas
FROM Usuario u
INNER JOIN Tiempo t ON u.username = t.empleado
WHERE fecha >= '2016-08-01' and fecha <= '2016-08-31'
GROUP BY u.id, t.empleado, CAST(MONTH(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(2)), CAST(YEAR(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

This is the output:

```
Id  empleado    MonthNumber YearNumber  Horas
86  username1   8           2016        96
95  username2   8           2016        80
99  username3   8           2016        47
102 username4   8           2016        85
```

And this is what I'm looking for:

```
Id  empleado    MonthNumber YearNumber  Horas
86  username1   8           2016        96
95  username2   8           2016        80
99  username3   8           2016        47
102 username4   8           2016        85
102 username5   8           2016        null (or 0)
```

> EDIT: Sample Data: [download](https://lagashsystems365-my.sharepoint.com/personal/danielq_lagash_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=NjBWiSzVytvz6ONZISaW3usnDq7OMMQu8sa4zC%2f992s%3d&docid=0271cd7a6f74445b2ad4510eaa78e0038&rev=1)

Comment: Replace Inner Join with Left Join

Comment: You should include sample data in your actual question, as links can break over time.  As it stands now, it isn't clear why any of the answers below are not at least partially fixing your problem.

Comment: @Sami, that would not achive the goal, stills get the same result. Please check out the sample data link I provide for a complete set for test.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you're right, I think I fixed the problem using `left outer join`, and combining `where` and `on` clause. In a minute I'll post the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data for the missing row exists in your table, you do a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.Id,
       COALESCE(t.empleado, 'NA')
       COALESCE(CAST(MONTH(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(2)), 'NA') AS MonthNumber,
       COALESCE(CAST(YEAR(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(4)), 'NA') AS YearNumber,
       SUM(t.horas) AS Horas
FROM Usuario u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tiempo t
    ON u.username = t.empleado AND
       fecha >= '2016-08-01' AND
       fecha <= '2016-08-31'
GROUP BY u.id,
         t.empleado,
         CAST(MONTH(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(2)),
         CAST(YEAR(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that but the output is the exactly the same as INNER and RIGHT.

Comment: @ChuckNorris -- I think you should move the `where` criteria to the `on` condition since `fecha` is in the `tiempo` table.  As is, it's negating the `outer join`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, question updated with sample data. Thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen question update with download link for a complete set of data to test.

Comment: @ChuckNorris Moved the `WHERE`condition to the `ON` clause and used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `left join`, but you have to be careful.  Conditions on the *second* table need to be in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT u.Id, t.empleado, CAST(MONTH(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS MonthNumber,
       CAST(YEAR(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS YearNumber,
       SUM(t.horas) AS Horas
FROM Usuario u LEFT JOIN
     Tiempo t
     ON u.username = t.empleado AND
        t.fecha >= '2016-08-01' AND t.fecha <= '2016-08-31'
GROUP BY u.id, t.empleado, CAST(MONTH(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(2)), CAST(YEAR(t.fecha) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Comment: Still trhows the same results, I'll provide an sqlfiddle in a minute.

Comment: My comment for @TimBiegeleisen solution says exactly this, isn't that better than posting another answer?  Regardless, your query is using an `inner join` above...

Comment: @sgeddes please post your answer for `left outer join` and moving the condition to `on`, that essentially does the trick. Thanks.